# One More Rails N+1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

-I have two models: `Game` and `Team`
Every game contains two teams in it. So i have one more model - `TeamParticipate`. It has game_id, team_id and additional fields, as winner and detailed score.
I want to show many games in one page, so I write `@games = Game.where(some_query).includes(:team_participates)`
Then, I want to show every two commands that participated in every game on page:

```
-@games.each do |game|
  =game.date
  -game.team_participates.each do |tp|
    =tp.team.title
```

I give aditional select query for every Team on the page. Is there a way to solve that problem and load page by 3 queries:

```
1) Select * from games where ...
2) Select * from team_participates where ...
3) Select * from teams where ...
```

Comment: `Game.includes(team_participates: :teams).where(.....)` will do if you had done the associations right.

Comment: That works, thanks!
Game.includes(team_participates: :team).where(.....)
I have only 3 select queries.

Comment: I'm giving it as an answer then, okay?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Game.includes(team_participates: :team).where(.....)` will do if you had done the associations right.

Comment: :team instead of :teams